# Is Object Oriented Modelling And Design part of Software Architecture?

Tags: uml

Is Object Oriented Modelling And Design part of Software Architecture?

I am confused between **Object Oriented Modelling & Design** and **Software Architecure**. In Software Achitecture we are providing the skeleton for system (as I understand) In Objet Oriented Modelling and design we design the system using different UML Digrams. So are we doing same thing in Software architecture ?

Because a skeleton could be defined using diagrams only,right?

Can someone please explain me with Example of Software architecture?

Comment: This question is off-topic, too conceptual, too far from programming.  Might be a better fit on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, Object Oriented **Modeling is a toolset** or process, Software **Architecture is a deliverable** artifact.

[image]

Related:

- [Wikipedia: Software architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_architecture)
- [Wikipedia: Object-oriented analysis and design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_analysis_and_design)
- [Kirill Fakhroutdinov's uml-diagrams.org: examples of UML diagrams documenting a software architecture](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/index-examples.html)
- [Scott W. Ambler's Agile Modeling: Architecture Envisioning: An Agile Best Practice](http://agilemodeling.com/essays/initialArchitectureModeling.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Software Architecture is a *very* broad term. It can describe the software of the tiniest component, to the largest systems.

OOMD is the process of arriving at a design that may be a part of a software architecture, typically by using Class Diagrams. But OOMD can be used outside of designing something new. It can be used to help analyse and understand a piece of legacy code.

UML is a language which is used in conjunction with OOMD. It is nothing more than that. A UML diagram doesn't necessarily 'contain' an architectual concept, just as much as a picture of an apple is an apple. One would use UML to illustrate and solidify concepts that will eventually go into the finished product.

Not all of UML is concerned with OOMD (eg. Use Cases, and Activity Diagrams). And not all of OOMD is concerned with Software Architecture.

Answer (score 1):

No, object oriented modelling and design is not part of the software architecture.

The software achitecture is independent of the platform that is used to implement it. The platform doesn't even have to be object oriented.

Software architecture has been around since before object oriented development even existed. I remember learning software achitecture approaches (JSP) before even hearing about object oriented development (OO was a very recent concept when I was in school).

Part of the software architecture could be used to automatically generate object models using some tool, but this a different part. By doing that you have taken the step beyond the software achitecture and chosen a platform for the implementation.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: @xmojmr: Removing an upvote doesn't cause a downvote. Besides, the question that you linked to isn't at all about recommended behaviour on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @xmojmr: What are you talking about?